# How do I store an php object in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, object, php

I have set up a table that has only one field for a BLOB (Binary large object) but when I try to Insert it into the table it throws an error stating that it failed to convert the object to a string. This is my Query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO objects (inquery) VALUES($inquery)");
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Serialize](http://php.net/serialize) it:

```
$str = serialize($object);
```

If your object contains private/protected fields it's also a good idea to `base64_encode()` the serialized object as those properties will result in ascii-1 characters being used which would break when editing the column manually e.g. with phpMyAdmin..

To restore your object, you simply [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) the string (`base64_decode()` it before if necessary).

Comment: So when I go to grab it from the table after it has been stored, how do i convert it back to an object?

Comment: `$object = unserialize($str);`

Comment: be careful though, not all php objects can be serialized. resources (db connects, http connections, etc) cannot be. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @contagious no worries, it is a dead simple object i created myself.

Answer (score 2):

use json_encode to encode the object before you save it in Mysql then json_decode to decode the object

Comment: When json_decoding the object will be a stdClass Object

Comment: sorry for the late response, but you can add the true to the second param something like this 

json_decode($json, true);