# Relation MySQL table , create an Array column in my table JAVA Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, arraylist

I'm creating a MySQL database about FIFA's World Cup, i have the "team" and "player" tables, i need to create in "team" table a column (ArrayList like Java) of "player" objects, but i dont know how i can do that, i need help please.

I created in "team" a Foreing Key referenced "player" table, but i need more than 1 player.
I need to create 22 foreing keys in "team" for all the players?

http://i.gyazo.com/645b723e49ef1eba46ac0487825035b4.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly try this:

Make a table "Team" with id_team as a primary key
Make a table "player" with id_player as a primary key
set id_team as a foreign key in table Player

that way you can select all players who have id_team == lets say 5

```
select * from Player where id_team = 5
```

here is the database model if it helps: [model](http://s13.postimg.org/epsswtb0n/Untitled.png)

It is not recommended to store whole objects into Mysql databases afaik, you should consider storing just a simple data like players name, players age etc. Then after selecting those data, rebuild those object from selected values. But if you insist on storing objects here is thread : [How do I store an php object in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054485/how-do-i-store-an-php-object-in-a-mysql-table)